# Unable to remove server header details with URLRewrite in IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, http-headers, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

I have two queries regarding URLRewrite module.

1. To remove server information from header I had installed URLRewrite module in IIS8.5 and added changes in web.config.

```
  <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
    <rule name="Remove Server header">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

but I am still able to see server details. Do I need to configure these values in IIS to work?

2. Also, can URLRewrite cause delay in response time?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/everything-you-might-need-about-iis-server-header-58ca268547be What choice do you have for 2. even if it has performance impact?

Answer (score 0):

1.I tested your outboundRules and it works normally on my side. did you add `RESPONSE_Server` to Server Variables? If not, please add it.

[image]

[image]

2.URL Rewrite will cause delay in response time, but usually it can be ignored.